# I'm unable to run AppImage applications in openSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: opensuse, executable

I recently had to reinstall my system (openSUSE Tumbleweed), and I'm experiencing some problems to run AppImage applications.

In particular, they are [FontBase](http://fontba.se/) and [Gravit Designer](https://designer.io/); the files are of course marked as executables, and are placed in a folder in my `/home`

They were perfectly running before the system re-installation, but now I can't get them to run; when trying to start them from CLI, I get the following error

```
GravitDesigner.AppImage: GravitDesigner.AppImage: cannot execute binary file
```

I've also tried to run them with `sudo`, with the same results.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run them again by changing permissions to `fusermount` binary, by running these commands as `root`:

```
chmod a+x /usr/bin/fusermount
chown root /usr/bin/fusermount
chmod u+s /usr/bin/fusermount
```

[Source, on AppImage forum](http://discourse.appimage.org/t/opensuse-leap-42-2-appimage-applications-will-not-run/197/5)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the default permissions for FUSE in openSUSE Tumbleweed reported in May: https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1041159

Please check that bug report for updates.

Answer (score -1):

Please do:

1. file ./GravitDesigner.AppImage (does it say "(...) ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64 (...)"?)
2. uname -p (does it say "x86_64"?)
3. chmod +x ./GravitDesigner.AppImage
4. ./GravitDesigner.AppImage

If that fails, please re-download and try again.
If that still fails, try with a different Linux installation (Live CD).

Comment: Like I wrote in my question, the apps were working before the system reinstall, it is not a problem of different architecture, and, like I said, they are set as executables; they are also residing in my home, so they were not changed, redownloading or trying them on another system is not going to help: it happens with **all** AppImage files, it is a problem related to my system, not to one of the executables.